# Why does VS clam this violates memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I needed to enforce some SSE memory boundaries for the code i'm writing but i'm having some trouble with Visual Studio's memory checker. I'm wondering why VS believes there is memory getting corrupted?

```
#define sse_t float* __restrict
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class AlignedContainer {
public:
    AlignedContainer(int n = 0, int frames = 0, size_t align = 16) {

        assert((align & (align - 1)) == 0);
        int bufferSize = sizeof(float) * n;
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
            int alignedSize = bufferSize + 15;
            auto aqbuf = new unsigned char[alignedSize];
            auto aligned = reinterpret_cast < unsigned char *>((reinterpret_cast < size_t > (aqbuf) + 15) & ~15); // 16 bit alignment in preperation for SSE
            memset(aqbuf, 0, alignedSize); // for debugging, forces memory to instantly allocate
            AcqBuffers.push_back(aqbuf);
            displayFrames.push_back(aligned);
        }
    }

    ~AlignedContainer() {
            for (int i = 0; i < AcqBuffers.size(); i++) {
                delete[]AcqBuffers[i];
            }
            AcqBuffers.empty();
            displayFrames.empty();
        }

inline sse_t operator [] (int i) const {
        return (sse_t) displayFrames[i];
    }

private:
        vector < void *>displayFrames;
        vector < void *>AcqBuffers;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int h = 2160;
    int w = 2544;
    AlignedContainer ac;
    ac = AlignedContainer(h * w, 4);
}
```

Error at the last line.

```
/***
*static int CheckBytes() - verify byte range set to proper value
*
*Purpose:
*       verify byte range set to proper value
*
*Entry:
*       unsigned char *pb       - pointer to start of byte range
*       unsigned char bCheck    - value byte range should be set to
*       size_t nSize            - size of byte range to be checked
*
*Return:
*       TRUE - if all bytes in range equal bcheck
*       FALSE otherwise
*
*******************************************************************************/
extern "C" static int __cdecl CheckBytes(
        unsigned char * pb,
        unsigned char bCheck,
        size_t nSize
        )
{
        while (nSize--)
        {
            if (*pb++ != bCheck)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Last line in which of the two code blocks?

Comment: can you post the error message please? would help us help you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i tried to run your code i discovered the following:

Your code is missing the rvalue assignment operator. Without it, it appears that the content of `AcqBuffers` gets moved when you call `ac = AlignedContainer(h * w, 4);`

Somehow the class still hols the content of `AcqBuffers` (after being moved) deleting it when destroyed. When the destructor of `ac` gets called then the destructor delets `AcqBuffers` again causing runtime error.

To fix this you need to add this:

```
AlignedContainer& operator = (AlignedContainer && rv)
{
    displayFrames = std::move(rv.displayFrames);
    AcqBuffers = std::move(rv.AcqBuffers);
    return (*this);
}
```

Raxvan.

Comment: To comment my question i saw you were using VS 2012, this will not work on standard c++03 , only on c++11 and above. @Joachim Pileborg explained what happens with the copying. it's interesting why the compiler doesn't generate a default deep copy operator since all the members have deep copy implementations

Comment: Not deep _enough_. The compiler will call the copy ctor of `std::vector<void*>`, and `std::vector<T>` will correctly copy a `T`. But a copy of `void*` necessarily is a shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
ac = AlignedContainer(h * w, 4);
```

first creates a temporary object, that is copied (with the copy-assignment operator) to `ac`. But because you don't provide the copy-assignment operator, the default one is invoked, and that does just do a shallow copying. So when the temporary object is destroyed the memory allocated by the temporary is deleted, so the `ac` object have pointers to unallocated memory, which it then tries to delete itself.

You need to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).